# finding some values after the specified text in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large text file and want to extract some values from these files. Required values are at two places (before and after some specified texts in all the files). I want the values which is after the specified text. I wrote following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os, glob

path = "./"
files = os.listdir(path)
for finding in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    file = os.path.join(path, finding)
    text = open(file, "r")
    CH = []   

    for line in text:
        if re.match("(.*)(XX)(.*)", line):
            CH.append(line)
    print CH
```

But this (as expected) script is printing all the XX values. How to edit this script to get the desired output. Following is the part of the large text file.

```
  ..................
  ..................  
  XX    1   -0.01910     
  XX    2    1.34832     
  XX    3   -2.36329     
  XX    4   -5.94807     
  XX    5    6.34862
  XX    6    core     
  Texts which I want to specify like (Normal)..........
  XX    1   -0.61910     
  XX    2    2.34832     
  XX    3   -0.06329     
  XX    4   -0.34807     
  XX    5    0.36862
  XX    6    [coreed   
  ..................
  ..................
```

The desired out put is as follows which is in the decreasing order of XX values after the text 'Normal'.

```
  XX     2.34832   
  XX     0.36862     
  XX    -0.06329     
  XX    -0.34807     
  XX    -0.61910
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm confused about the regex you do have written '(.*)(XX)(.*)'.  Am I correct you want all the 3rd field from the lines that begin with (whitespace and then) XX.  Or rather those lines after "Texts which I want to specify"?

The most straightforward way I can think of is to carry around a boolean to indicate if you've found this special line of text "Texts which I want to specify like (Normal).........." yet.  For example...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os, glob

path = "./"
files = os.listdir(path)
for finding in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    file = os.path.join(path, finding)
    text = open(file, "r")
    CH = []   
    doPayAttention = False

    for line in text:
        if re.match("Texts which I want to specify", line):
            doPayAttention = True
            continue
        if not doPayAttention:
            continue
        mm = re.match(r"^\s*XX\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s*$", line)
        if mm is not None:
            CH.append(mm.group(1))
    CH = sorted(CH, reversed=True)
    for _ch in CH:
        print 'XX ', _ch
```

Also it depending on how much you trust your files, using string.split() ought to give you more readable code, without the power of regex. Finally, it should be noted that this is a particularly simple AWK program.

```
awk '/Texts which I want to specify/,EOF {print $1 " " $3}' | sort -n
```